# How can I parse this text into a table in Python?

Tags: python, text-parsing

I have this data called text.txt. I also have my code below. I want to extract line values and want to make a table out of it. I also wanted to see if there is a better way to do it. Thanks

test.txt

```
Counting********************File:  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_1_CATGGC_L003_R1_001
Seq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: 
0
Seq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: 
73764
Counting********************File:  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_2_CATTTT_L003_R1_001
Seq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: 
0
Seq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: 
78640
Counting********************File:  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_VF_1_CAACTA_L003_R1_001.fastq
Seq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: 
0
Seq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: 
26267
```

result I want:

```
  File Name                                 Seq_132582_1  Seq_483974_49238
0  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_1_CATGGC_L003_R1_001     0      73764
1  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_SsHV2L_2_CATTTT_L003_R1_001     0      78640
2  bbduk_trimmed_Ago2_VF_1_CAACTA_L003_R1_001.fastq   0      26267
```

code I tried:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("Python 3 or a more recent version is required.")
import re
import pandas as pd
text = open("text.txt",'r').read()
print(type(text))
results = re.findall(r'(bbduk_trimmed.*.fastq)\nSeq_132582_1: ATCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTCT: \n(\d)\nSeq_483974_49238: TCCGAATTAGTGTAGGGGTTAACATAACTC: \n(\d*)',text)
df=pd.DataFrame(results)
# df.columns=['FileName','Seq_132582_1','Seq_483974_49238'] #This doesn't work
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your regex with below code line:

```
re.findall(r'Counting[*]+File:[ ]*([\w.]+)[ \n]*[ :\w]+[\n]*(\w+)[\n]*[ :\w]+[\n]*(\w+)', text)
```

**Explanation:**

- `[*]+` - match one or more `*` character
- `[ ]*` - match one or more  (space) character
- `([\w.]+)` - match filename and compute as first paranthasis
- `[ \n]*` - match zero or more space or newline character
- `[ :\w]+` - match your whole line which is starting with `Seq`

The core logic to get sequence in the regex is as below:

`([\w.]+)[ \n]*[ \w]+:[ :\w]+[\n]*(\w+)`

- after matching filename with `([\w.]+)` first, we match the space(s) and new lines(s) using `[ \n]*`,
- after that if you want to parse name of sequence you are parsing you might need to keep `[ \w]+:[ :\w]+` separately and use it as `([ \w])+:[ :\w]+` where paranthisis can match you can extract sequence which can be `Seq_132582_1` or `Seq_483974_49238`, however if order is not to be considered then you may simply replace it with `[ :\w]+[\n]*` and match the whole line and match the data you require on next line with `(\w+)`

Another easier way is to extract data is shown below to prepare result without using `re` module:

```
results = []
f = open("content.txt", 'r')

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    file_name = line.split(":")[-1].strip()
    f.readline()  # skip line 
    data_seq1 = f.readline().strip()
    f.readline()  # skip line 
    data_seq2 = f.readline().strip()
    results.append((file_name, data_seq1, data_seq2))
```

Comment: Thanks! what if I have more Seqs? what regex do I need to add?